# Change textview dynamically in Viewflipper

Tags: java, android, viewflipper

pretty easy question here, but I am not a java superuser quite yet.

I am using a ViewFlipper to provide a number of images, and a sliding-drawer to contain text specific to each image. I would like to have the text of the sliding drawer change to a specific string dependent on which child view is currently displayed.
Here is the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/previous" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Prev" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/next" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image1"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image2"></ImageView>
            </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the java:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);


            flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
            next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
            imageview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



            next.setOnClickListener(this);
            previous.setOnClickListener(this);
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == next) {
                flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
                flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
                flipper.showNext();
            }

            if (v == previous) {
                flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
                flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
                flipper.showPrevious();

            }
            }
```

I'm sure the answer is really obvious, but that's why I need your help....THANKS!

Comment: Where is your slidingdrawer code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `showNext()` and `showPrevious()`, update your `TextView` to match.